# Vlookup with VBA/Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to do something for work. I used SAP script to get some information from SAP and then I merged 2 columns together to get a unique value in column P on the MRPMon worksheet.

The beginning of this shows me copying and pasting the concatenated column to column A on the MRPCont worksheet

```
Sub Vlookup ( )

Dim sourceColumn As Range
Dim destinationColumn As Range
Dim WSF As Worksheet
Dim WSO As Worksheet
Dim lookupRange As Range
Dim FinalRow1 As Integer
Dim FinalRow2 As Integer
Dim i As Long

set WSF = Worksheets ("MRPMon")
Set WSO = Worksheets ("MRPCont")

'Set the source column range
Set sourceColumn = WSF.Range("P:P")
'Set the destination column range
Set destinationColumn = WSO.Range ("A:A")

'Copy the values from the source column to the destination column

sourceColumn.Copy Destination: =destinationColumn

FinalRow1 = WSF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
FinalRow2 = WSO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(×lUp).Row

Set lookupRange = WSF.Range("A1:P" & FinalRow1)

For i = 2 To FinalRow2
WSO.Cells(i,2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WSO.Cells(i, 1).Value, lookupRange, 2, False)

Next i

End Sub
```

This gives me a debug error (Unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetFunction class) on "WSO.Cells(i,2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WSO.Cells(i, 1).Value, lookupRange, 2, False)". Prior to that I was getting N/A

Comment: Missing a `Set` before `lookupRange = WSF.Range ("Al:P" & FinalRow2)`. Also `Al` doesn't look valid. Did you mean `A1`?

Comment: Yes I did. It’s A1

Comment: `.End(x1Up).Row` should be `xlUp` like the line below.  If you always use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module it will tell you about this type of problem.

Comment: The way I copied this from my laptop messed up with the numbers and letters. It is xlUp on my computer not 1

Comment: Then maybe edit the post to reflect the code you're actually using, so we're not focusing on typos, and tell use more about the "debug error" you're getting?  What's the error message, and on which line of code?

Comment: You didn't fix the problem pointed out in the first comment (missing `Set`)

Comment: Couldn't you paste a VLOOKUP formula instead (or, better, an INDEX/MATCH one) bring it down and have the workbook calculate it? Since you are using the formula in the macro and the values are not being stored, but written, it would be faster and it would also take less lines to do it.

Comment: You updated to add `Set`, but are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Thank you Tim. That cleared the error. Now I'm getting an error with vlookup property worksheetFunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a run-time error with the `Vlookup()`, then it's best to drop the `WorksheetFunction` part and instead test the return value (which is an error if there' no match)

```vb
Dim res
'...
'...
For i = 2 To FinalRow2
    res = Application.VLookup(WSO.Cells(i, 1).Value, lookupRange, 2, False)
    If IsError(res) Then rs = "No Match!" 'for example 
    WSO.Cells(i,2).Value = res
Next i
```

Comment: It says there’s no match but this is weird because I copied and pasted the lookup values from that worksheet. So it shouldn’t be giving me no match right?

Comment: It's difficult for me to say.  If you enter a vlookup formula manually, does it make a match?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Tim. It wasn’t picking up the combined values because it was in column P. Once I moved this to column A, it worked.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please flag as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This helps anyone coming along later with a similar question to see there's a working solution.